# Как создать контейнер переменной высоты?

Tags: html, css

Создаю свой динамический сайт. Сайт будет содержать в себе довольно много статей, очевидно, что каждая статья будет иметь свой размер. Оформление сайта готово, но как сделать, чтобы его основное тело (Где и будет контент) было НЕ фиксированного размера, а раздвигалось в случае необходимости?

Comment: Любой контейнер изначально имеет переменную высоту

Answer (score 3):

Если не задавать высоту родителя, то его высота и будет равна общей высоте потомков (плюс отступы и бордеры). Как-то так, если правильно понял вопрос. Если же нужно, чтобы основной блок держал минимальную высоту до раздвигания, задавайте min-height

Comment: Да, вы все поняли верно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container-razdvigalka{min-height:...px}
```

Минимально будет сколько зададите, дальше будет удлиняться.

Answer (score 1):

если честно, не понятно в чем вопрос, у вас что сайт всегда имеет фиксированную высоту? зачем такое вообще делаете? уберите height который задаете контейнеру с контентом и он сам будет вытягиваться вниз